# Swift compiler hanging up (possibly on type-inference of generic parameters)

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, functional-programming, type-inference

I recently wrote a function and some associated code that acts as a sort of switch expression (which worked as expected) and [posted it on CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/131214/49673)

I have since started to try and improve my own code and seem to have hit a wall, as it seems that my code makes the playground hang up and won't compile when put in a project either. However, when typing everything out in a project, Xcode doesn't complain until I actually try to build it. Here's what I have:

```
func caze<T: Equatable, R>(vals: T..., @autoclosure(escaping) ret f: () -> R) -> (AnySequence<T>, () -> R) {
    return (AnySequence(vals), f)
}

func caze<T, R where T: Equatable, T: ForwardIndexType>(range: Range<T>, @autoclosure(escaping) ret f: () -> R) -> (AnySequence<T>, () -> R) {
    return (AnySequence(range), f)
}


func schwitch<T: Equatable, R>(value: T, _ cases: (AnySequence<T>, () -> R)..., @autoclosure def: () throws -> R) rethrows -> R {
    for (vals, f) in cases {
        if vals.contains(value) {
            return f()
        }
    }
    return try def()
}

func test() {
    schwitch(5,
         caze(0, ret: "hello"),
         caze(1, 2, ret: "test"),
         caze(3..<7, ret: "lol"),
         def: "nop")

    schwitch("helloo",
        caze("hello", "Hello", ret: "test"),
        def: "nop")
}
```

And this is the error I get when trying to build the project:

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

And the stack trace:

```
0  swift                    0x000000010c7f366b llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 43
1  swift                    0x000000010c7f2956 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 70
2  swift                    0x000000010c7f3ccf SignalHandler(int) + 287
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff87f0752a _sigtramp + 26
4  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007f82f4bf0418 _sigtramp + 1825476360
5  swift                    0x000000010ab9e994 (anonymous namespace)::ApplyClassifier::classifyRethrowsArgument(swift::Expr*, swift::Type) + 52
6  swift                    0x000000010ab9ea2b (anonymous namespace)::ApplyClassifier::classifyRethrowsArgument(swift::Expr*, swift::Type) + 203
7  swift                    0x000000010ab9f02a (anonymous namespace)::ApplyClassifier::classifyRethrowsArgument(swift::Expr*, swift::Type) + 1738
8  swift                    0x000000010ab9e56c (anonymous namespace)::ApplyClassifier::classifyApply(swift::ApplyExpr*) + 652
9  swift                    0x000000010ab9dc86 (anonymous namespace)::ErrorHandlingWalker<(anonymous namespace)::CheckErrorCoverage>::walkToExprPre(swift::Expr*) + 278
10 swift                    0x000000010ac45854 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::Traversal, swift::Expr*, swift::Stmt*, bool, swift::Pattern*, bool, void>::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 148
11 swift                    0x000000010ac42ef7 swift::Stmt::walk(swift::ASTWalker&) + 87
12 swift                    0x000000010ab9d9d5 swift::TypeChecker::checkFunctionErrorHandling(swift::AbstractFunctionDecl*) + 405
13 swift                    0x000000010ab7ef1b typeCheckFunctionsAndExternalDecls(swift::TypeChecker&) + 1451
14 swift                    0x000000010ab7f665 swift::performTypeChecking(swift::SourceFile&, swift::TopLevelContext&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckingFlags, unsigned int>, unsigned int) + 1765
15 swift                    0x000000010aa00eb4 swift::CompilerInstance::performSema() + 4580
16 swift                    0x000000010a543596 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&) + 934
17 swift                    0x000000010a54268d frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 2781
18 swift                    0x000000010a53e0ac main + 1932
19 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff912a35ad start + 1
```

The problem seems to be using the function, since everything compiles fine if I leave out that part. Just using the `caze` also seems to work okay, as the following works as expected as well:

```
caze(5, ret: "hello")
let test: (AnySequence<Int>, () -> String) = caze(0...5, ret: "hello") // Swift needs some help figuring out which function to use here
```

Is this simply a bug in the Swift compiler or am I missing something?

Comment: Compiler should never fail even your code have issue. You should file a bug.

Comment: @BryanChen good point, I'll get on that. I'd still like to figure out what is going on and how to get around it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: as Bryan already said, it is certainly a compiler bug, it should **never** crash.

---

To address the problem: the root cause seems to be the `rethrows`, since using the following compiles and runs without any problems. That matches up with the stack traces `5 - 7 classifyRethrowsArgument`.

```
func schwitch<T: Equatable, R>(value: T, cas cases: (AnySequence<T>, () -> R)..., @autoclosure def: () -> R) -> R {
    for (vals, f) in cases {
        if vals.contains(value) {
            return f()
        }
    }
    return def()
}
```

Same goes for

```
func schwitch<T: Equatable, R>(value: T, cas cases: (AnySequence<T>, () -> R)..., @autoclosure def: () throws -> R) -> R {
    for (vals, f) in cases {
        if vals.contains(value) {
            return f()
        }
    }
    return try! def()
}
```

I am aware of the fact that is far from a complete answer but I wanted to give at least some kind of hint to what I have found out. If you do not *need* the default case to be able to throw this code should work for you. I will try to figure out why the `rethrows` causes the problem.

The [`TypeCheckError.cpp`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/Sema/TypeCheckError.cpp) of the swift compiler might be helpful in figuring this out.

Comment: Good catch, that I can't have a rethrow there is a shame, but not that big of a deal at the moment since I haven't figured out how to rethrow errors from in the cases anyway.

Comment: @overactor throwing from the cases works exactly the same way, you just have to put a `throws` in a lot of places :D